# Why am I not able to print 32.0 instead of 32 inspite of typeconversion?

Tags: c++, syntax, statistics, type-conversion, weighted-average

So Here's my code. the inputs are

> 5

> 10 40 30 50 20

> 1 2 3 4 5

I'm trying to find the weighted mean of an array of size n, vector a holding the n elements with their corresponding weights in vector b. I'm unable to understand why 32 is being printed out instead of 32.0? Can someone tell me why and how I can change it?

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> a(n),b(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>> a[i] ;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>> b[i] ;
    }
    double s=0,w=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        s+=b[i]*a[i];
        w+=b[i];
    }
    cout<<s/w*1.0;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it prints `32` or `32.0` is a subject of output formatting. By default, it clips all unnecessary digits (and the decimal point as well) if possible. (The `*1.0` doesn't help for this.)

The relevant functions are available in `<iomanip>`:

- [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)
- [std::setfixed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfixed).

Example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << 32.0 << '\n'
    << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << 32.0 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
32
32.0
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3cb3f7d64bdf7cc)

Answer (score 2):

c++ `cout` automatically removes trailing zeroes by default.

If you wish to see them, you must use `std::cout << std::fixed;` see detail from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/?kw=fixed).

Also, if you wish to set the precision of the float, use `std::cout.precision(N)`.
Check [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/?kw=precision) for the detailed info.

I'd change your code as below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> a(n),b(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>> a[i] ;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>> b[i] ;
    }
    double s=0,w=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        s+=b[i]*a[i];
        w+=b[i];
    }
    // MODIFIED
    cout << fixed;
    cout.precision(1);
    // MODIFIED END
    cout<<s/w*1.0;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to have output formatting, the way to do that would be to use `iomanip` function of `setprecision` as follow:

```
    std::cout << std::fixed; 
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1); //setprecision(n) where n = number of decimal digits
    std::cout <<s/w << '\n';\
```